# Copying Python built from source from one machine to another

Tags: python-3.x, cpython, rhel7

I built a fresh version of Python 3.11 one one machine (RHEL7) and I want to copy this instance to a fleet VMs.  Is there a way to copy all of the required dependencies from  the machine to another?

Does Python provide a script to building a rpm perhaps?

Comment: Check where *make install* dumps files (there are a bunch of folders).

Comment: Couldn't you see what an existing package does?  E.g. https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python3.12/blob/rawhide/f/python3.12.spec or maybe just check to see which files get installed by that package?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was building with the `--prefix` flag which was building an executable that was looking for dependencies in a hardcoded folder. I rebuilt without the prefix, and all the files that I needed were in `/usr/local`